# Laravel 7 change where file uploads to

Tags: file-upload, laravel-7

I have a file upload form in on of my blade files.
However when I upload the file I see its saving the file to /storage//Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpIVfP2L.mp4 how do I set this upload to be saved to a specific location like I want them saved in the Laravel public folder that is in the Laravel root directory so the path would be /public/trainingvideos

Below is my controller code where my file upload code is

```
public function addtraining(Request $req) {
    //Save to a mysql database
    //print_r($req->input());
    $pwdata = new AddTraining;
    $pwdata->userid = $req->userid;
    $pwdata->video_title = $req->trainingtitle;
    $pwdata->video_description = $req->trainingdesc;
    $pwdata->video_url = $req->trainingvideo;

    if($req->hasFile('trainingvideo')) {
        //  Let's do everything here
        if($req->file('trainingvideo')->isValid()) {
            //
            $validated = $req->validate([
                'trainingvideo' => 'mimes:mp4,mov|max:10000',
            ]);
            $extension = $req->trainingvideo->extension();
            $req->trainingvideo->storeAs('public_path()/public/trainingvideos', $req->trainingvideo.".".$extension);
            $url = Storage::url($req->trainingvideo.".".$extension);
            $pwdata->video_url = $url;
            //Session::flash('success', "Success!");
           
        }
    }
    //abort(500, 'Could not upload video :(');
    $pwdata->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/tmp` directory is where files are temporarily stored when uploaded.

In your controller you need to go about actually storing that file, the docs cover this in depth; https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files

It's worth mentioning that if you leave the files in your `tmp` directory, they will be garbage collected at some point and so this is not a safe location to store files.

Comment: Thank you. So I am trying to use the storeAs() function but it does not seem to save the file in that location. Am I missing a function in my code?

Comment: Where does it save the file? Are you definitely hitting that block of code? I can see it is guarded by an if condition.